# error getting specific data from data base via id

Tags: reactjs, database

I need to render balance and employee data to the user via `axios.get` using the specific `post id` from `useParams` hook. I tried to render the data in the JSX without mapping and got the following error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {message, data}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

I don't think I need to map the data, but I tried it and got this error:

```
TypeError: balance.map is not a function
```

Neither seems to work. I am sure this a simple fix but I can't seem to figure it out. I consoled `res. data` and printing the data just fine:

```
{message: "Post found", data: {…}}
data:
balance: 5
company: "ABC"
date: "2021-07-14T23:52:29.896Z"
employee: "Jane Hines"
fee: false
notes: ""
tax: false
__v: 0
_id: "60daac85f9243d290489eac1"
__proto__: Object
message: "Post found"
__proto__: Object
```

, so I know it's the JSX that is the issue. What did I do wrong?

**Here is what I want the component to say:**
`Jane Doe's new balance is 3.00`

attempt 1 without map

```
import  { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Success = () => {
    const [balance, setBalance] = useState("");
    const [employee, setEmployee] = useState("");
    const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");
    const { id } = useParams();

    useEffect(() => {
        axios
        .get(`http://localhost:5000/get-snapshot-id/${id}`)
        .then((res) => {
            console.log(res.data);
            setBalance(res.data);
            setEmployee(res.data);
            setNotes(res.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    }, [setBalance, setEmployee, setNotes]);

    return(
    <>
    <h2>Successfully Updated Balance!</h2>
    <h4> {employee}'s new balance is {balance}</h4>

    <button><a href="/search-comp-details">Continue seraching</a></button>
    <button><a href="/main">Back to Main</a></button>
    </>
    )
}
export default Success;
```

attempt 2 with map

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import axios from "axios";

const Success = () => {
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState([]);
  // const [employee, setEmployee] = useState("");
  // const [notes, setNotes] = useState("");
//   const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/get-snapshot-id/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        // setData(res.data);
        console.log(res.data);
        setBalance(res.data);
        // setEmployee(res.data);
        // setNotes(res.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Successfully Updated Balance!</h2>
      {balance.map((d) => (
        <h4 key={d.id}>
          {d.employee}'s new balance is {d.balance}
        </h4>
      ))}

      <button>
        <a href="/search-comp-details">Continue seraching</a>
      </button>
      <button>
        <a href="/main">Back to Main</a>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
export default Success;
```

Comment: One or both of `employee` and `balance` is updated to be an object with keys `message` and `data`. Which are you wanting to render? Can you share/add that response to your question?

Comment: @DrewReese i updated thanks for the responce

Comment: Oh, sorry, that last request was terribly unclear. Can you add what the value of `res.data`, or what is outputted from `console.log(res.data);` is?

Comment: @DrewReese updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out, I needed to call the data object with in the data object:
instead of `console.log(res.data)` i needed `console.log(res.data.data)`,
so to get the balance data i needed : `setBalance(res.data.data.balance)`

It wasn't the JSX that was the issue it was the Axios req.

Answer (score 1):

With a `res.data` response object:

```
{message: "Post found", data: {…}}

data:
  balance: 5
  company: "ABC"
  date: "2021-07-14T23:52:29.896Z"
  employee: "Jane Hines"
  fee: false
  notes: ""
  tax: false
```

it seems you want the `balance` and `employee` properties from the nested `data` property, i.e. `res.data.data.balance`.

You can either save the entire `res.data` object and reference into the nested keys. Remember to use valid initial state of the same type and conditionally render the result when available.

```
const Success = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({}); // <-- object type
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/get-snapshot-id/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setData(res.data.data);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!data.employee && !data.balance) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Successfully Updated Balance!</h2>
      <h4 key={d.id}>
        {data.employee}'s new balance is {data.balance}
      </h4>

      <button>
        <a href="/search-comp-details">Continue searching</a>
      </button>
      <button>
        <a href="/main">Back to Main</a>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Or save the nested state individually and do the same as above.

```
const Success = () => {
  const [balance, setBalance] = useState('');
  const [employee, setEmployee] = useState("");
  const { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get(`http://localhost:5000/get-snapshot-id/${id}`)
      .then((res) => {
        setBalance(res.data.data.balance); // <-- get nested values
        setEmployee(res.data.data.employee);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);

  if (!employee && !balance) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }

  return (
    <>
      <h2>Successfully Updated Balance!</h2>
      <h4 key={d.id}>
        {employee}'s new balance is {balance}
      </h4>

      <button>
        <a href="/search-comp-details">Continue searching</a>
      </button>
      <button>
        <a href="/main">Back to Main</a>
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: thank you I figured it out, I did try the second solution you have on here before, and got nothing, I needed to do the below to get the result.. thanks so much for always lending me a helping hand!

Comment: @Julie Anytime, always happy to help fellow devs.